# Kendo ComboBox Selection Not Applying to Underlying ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI in ASP.NET MVC, and I have yet to be able to bind a Kendo ComboBox to an underlying ViewModel property using my current editor template setup.  The ComboBox has been configured to have a pre-populated drop-down and to show suggestions based on what the user has typed in the box.  The suggestions and auto-population work perfectly and I'm able to select from my pre-built list, but each time my ViewModel is returned to the controller, the property is null as though nothing was selected.  I'm using an editor template that accepts the Type of the property, using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Label, "LabelTemplate")` to bind to the ViewModel property on the page, then `@Html.ComboBoxFor(m => m)` to bind the editor to individual object properties. Here is the code that I am using (abridged to contain relevant sections):

#### My ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{  
    [Column("Label")]
    public LabelModel Label { get; set; }
}
```

#### LabelModel:

```
public class LabelModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public char Character { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => Name;
}
```

#### LabelModel Editor Template

```
@model MyProject.Models.LabelModel

<script>
    function editLabelCode() {
        return {
            text: $("#EditLabelList").data("kendoComboBox")._prev
        };
    }
</script>

@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
    .Name("EditLabelList")
    .Placeholder("Enter Label Name")
    .DataValueField("Code")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .MinLength(1)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("Labels_Read", "Data")
                .Data("editLabelCode");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

#### MainView.cshtml:

```
@model SafetyPortalWeb.Models.MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Label, "LabelTemplate")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Label)
```

As mentioned above, the ComboBox populates the list selection perfectly.  I have no issues pulling my pre-generated list or using the ComboBox search and suggestion functionality.  When I save, though, this LabelModel property comes back `null` for all of its values.  There are other properties on the ViewModel that get populated correctly (I didn't include them here to cut down on the code I'm pasting), so it's not an overall issue with Model binding or saving.

I am relatively new to ASP.NET MVC, so I fully expect that there is something obvious I may be missing.  I have poured over similar SO questions for days, and have yet to find an answer that has worked for this setup.  Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

#### ** Update **:

I have gotten a bit closer by following @SteveGreene 's advice and taking it a bit further.

If I remove the `.Name()` property from the ComboBox and instead bind it to a *property* on LabelModel instead of the model itself, I am able to get values returned on the property I bind to.  However, I'm hoping to be able to bind to the entire LabelModel *object*, and be able to set that object to the corresponding property on the ViewModel.  I.e....

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.Code)
    .Placeholder("Enter Label Name")
    .DataValueField("Code")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .AutoBind(true)
    .MinLength(1)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("Labels_Read", "Data")
                .Data("editLabelCode");
        })
        .ServerFiltering(true);
    })
)
```

Configured this way, I'm able to set the `Code` property on the LabelModel by selecting an item, but none of the other properties carry over from the ComboBox selection.  I know they are present in the element because `Name` is used as the display text for each item, and they display correctly.  Is there a way to ensure that I set the entire object when it's selected?  Trying to bind to the model using `ComboBoxFor(m => m)` instead causes no properties to be set when selected.

Comment: Is m.Label or type MyProject.Models.LabelModel?

Comment: Take out `.Name("EditLabelList")` - when you use xxxxxxxFor() versions the name and Id are automatically assigned.

Comment: @RossBush It is, but I made a typo in the ViewModel property.  It's a LabelModel Type.

Comment: @SteveGreene Ok, that makes sense.  What will the name of the HTML element be in that case?

Comment: @SteveGreene I've tried two versions of your suggestion - first I removed the `.Name` property from `ComboBoxFor()` and named the HTML element by passing it as the third parameter in `EditorFor`m with the same results.  Then, I tried removing all of the naming attempts, and only referring to the element in my function by the name of the property I'm binding to.  The JS function still works to pre-populate a list, so I'm guessing I named it correctly, but in that configuration the Label property comes back as being completely null, whereas before the object was at least instantiated.  Closer?

Comment: We generally don't bind to objects. We would have a field in our viewmodel like `ColorId` and bind to that. Might need to add `.ValuePrimitive(true)` for that.

Comment: @SteveGreene Thank you for the followup.  Unfortunately, that still didn't work - the object is initialized (because I construct it before passing the ViewModel to the View), but all of the properties are default.  Messing with `.ValuePrimitive()` didn't seem to change the behavior in any of the configurations.

Comment: When you create a template with a built in control for a template editor you can use a blank name and it will auto name it. I've found with kendo this doesnt work but you could try this....

Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m)
    .Name(Html.NameFor(m => m))....

Comment: If I recall, the name of the editor component has to be identical to the name of the property for binding. Perhaps your Template should have .Name("LabelModel") instrad of .Name("EditLabelList")